# Frame expert system

Tags: expert-system

What's the best way to write a simple frame-based expert system, which determines if object is relative to some group? It's a kind of lab work for Intelligent Systems course in university. Or are there any OpenSource projects to study it's realization?

Answer (score 1):

We used [LPA's Flex](http://www.lpa.co.uk/flx.htm) which is a toolkit that sits on top of win-prolog.  It does frame based expert systems and they have an education programme.